# Snowflake CSV file format does not handle timestamps as expected

Tags: sql, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in Snowflake with a timestamp column, defined like so:

```
last_updated_utc TIMESTAMP_NTZ NOT NULL
```

and I have a CSV file format defined like this:

```
CREATE FILE FORMAT IF NOT EXISTS MY_DATABASE.MY_SCHEMA.assets_format
    TYPE = CSV
    COMPRESSION = AUTO
    FIELD_DELIMITER = '|'
    SKIP_HEADER = 1
    SKIP_BLANK_LINES = TRUE
    DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    TIME_FORMAT = 'HH:MI:SS.FFTZH'
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.FFTZH'
    TRIM_SPACE = TRUE
```

The problem I'm having is that, if I attempt to copy staged data using this copy statement:

```
COPY INTO MY_DATABASE.MY_SCHEMA.my_table 
    FROM (SELECT s.$1, s.$2, s.$3, s.$4, s.$5, s.$6, s.$7, s.$8, 
            s.$9 IF s.$9 IS NOT NULL ELSE '', s.$10, s.$11, s.$12, 
            s.$13, s.$14, s.$15, s.$16
        FROM @MY_DATABASE.MY_SCHEMA.%my_table/Pdata s)
    FILE_FORMAT = ( FORMAT_NAME = 'MY_DATABASE.MY_SCHEMA.assets_format' )
    PATTERN = '.*[.]csv[.]gz' 
    PURGE = TRUE 
    ON_ERROR = 'SKIP_FILE'
```

I get the following error, very deep in the file:

> Timestamp '2022-08-11T00:00:00Z' is not recognized.

I figured this was an issue with how I had defined my timestamp format, so I tried the following:

```
USE DATABASE MY_DATABASE;
ALTER SESSION SET TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.FFTZH';
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('2022-08-11T00:00:00Z')
```

but this worked. So, I'm not sure what I'm actually doing wrong here.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related but one issue here is that you are loading timestamps with a timezone included into a TIMESTAMP_NTZ column, which does not store the timezone offset i.e. you are losing the timezone component of the data as you load it. I recommend you change this to TIMESTAMP_TZ.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths True, but all the timestamps are guaranteed to be in UTC so I don't need the timezone portion.

Comment: Personally I would never trust a "guarantee" and always plan for the worst, but YMMV :)

Comment: @NathanGriffiths Ooh but you've gone and pushed that button. Point taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly with the default TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT:

```
ALTER SESSION UNSET TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT;
```

```
select column1
    ,try_to_timestamp(column1) as t1
    ,try_to_timestamp_ntz(column1) as t2
    ,try_to_timestamp_ntz(column1, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.FFTZH') as t3
    ,try_to_timestamp_tz(column1, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.FFTZH') as t4
    ,try_to_timestamp_ntz(column1, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.FF') as t5
    ,try_to_timestamp_ntz(column1, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.FFZ') as t6
from values
('2022-08-11T00:00:00Z'),
('2022-08-11T00:00:00');
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 | T5 | T6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-11T00:00:00Z | 2022-08-11 00:00:00.000 | 2022-08-11 00:00:00.000 | null | null | null | null |
| 2022-08-11T00:00:00 | 2022-08-11 00:00:00.000 | 2022-08-11 00:00:00.000 | null | null | 2022-08-11 00:00:00.000 | null |

and

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('2022-08-11T00:00:00Z')
```

gives:

| TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('2022-08-11T00:00:00Z') |
| --- |
| 2022-08-11 00:00:00.000 |

Thus the format is not actually correct for the timestamps (as per the first results) and the inbuilt parsers handle your string by default. If I change you use your format, all timestamps fail to parse.

So given you have no Millisecond in you input string I would drop the `FF` clause, and given you do not have Timezone Hours I would drop `TZH`

but for me on the default timestamp formats, all three work:

```
select column1
    ,try_to_timestamp_ntz(column1) as t1
    ,try_to_timestamp_ntz(column1, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.FFTZH') as t2
    ,try_to_timestamp_ntz(column1, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SSZ') as t3
from values
('2022-08-11T00:00:00Z');
```

| COLUMN1 | T1 | T2 | T3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-11T00:00:00Z | 2022-08-11 00:00:00.000 | null | 2022-08-11 00:00:00.000 |

Comment: `t2` in your solution returns null.

Comment: @Woody1193 that is what I was expecting... but I was getting results: and it seems I am getting cached results, not sure how they are matching..

Comment: Interesting. Anyway, your `t1` solution fixed my issue. I was hoping to explicitly state my timestamp format in case Snowflake changes their default but I'll rely on that for now. Thanks for your response.